# Python List comprehension one declaration and 2 Comprehensions

Tags: python

How can I combine this:

```
ipaddresses =  [ipadr['ip'] for ipadr in hosts]
for ipadr in ipaddresses:
    ips = '.'.join(str(i) for i in ipadr)
```

Into One declaration with 2 list comprehensions? I just don't get it. Thanks

ipaddresses will print something like this:

> [[10, 10, 10, 10], [10, 20, 20, 20]]

Comment: my hosts ia json data, however it was solved thanks to Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams !

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You only need 1 LC, not 2.

```
['.'.join(str(octet) for octet in addr['ip']) for addr in hosts]
```